# How do you find greatest number among 5 with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, find, max

This is code for finding maximum in 3 but i want the code for finding maximum amoung 5:

```
Dim a, b, c As Integer

a = InputBox("enter 1st no.") 
b = InputBox("enter 2nd no.") 
c = InputBox("enter 3rd no.")

If a > b Then 
    If a > c Then 
        MsgBox("A is Greater") 
    Else 
        MsgBox("C is greater") 
    End If 
Else 
    If b > c Then 
        MsgBox("B is Greater") 
    Else 
        MsgBox("C is Greater")
    End If 
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David suggested, keep your values in a list. That's easier than using individual variables and can be extended to as many values as requested (up to millions of values).

If you need to keep individual variables for some reason, do this:

```
Dim max As Integer = a
Dim name As String = "A"
If b > max Then
    max = b
    name = "B"
End If
If c > max Then
    max = c
    name = "C"
End If
If d > max Then
    max = d
    name = "D"
End If
' ...  extend to as many variables as you need.
MsgBox(name & " is greater")
```

Comment: Greate !! this is what i need

Answer (score 17):

Put the values into an array and use [the `Max` function on `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx):

```
'Requires Linq for Max() function extension
Imports System.Linq
'This is needed for List
Imports System.Collections.Generic

' Create a list of Long values. 
Dim longs As New List(Of Long)(New Long() _
                                   {4294967296L, 466855135L, 81125L})

' Get the maximum value in the list. 
Dim max As Long = longs.Max()

' Display the result.
MsgBox("The largest number is " & max)

' This code produces the following output: 
' 
' The largest number is 4294967296
```

Comment: To answer the OP you should return the index of the largest.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: I thought about that, yes.  Really this is just copied/pasted from the linked MSDN page.  Though it's not really clear from the OP's code what he's actually doing or why.  It is clear, however, that there's much room for improvement.

Comment: Hes a newb for sure but his code does give the letter index of the max number. Its actually not as trivial to do on IEnumerable as you might think. Google MaxBy

Comment: **IMPORTANT** Please note the `.Max()` function requires the `Imports System.Linq`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for you,

```
Dim xMaxNo As Integer
Dim xTemp As Integer

For i as integer = 1 To 5
   xTemp =  InputBox("enter No: " & i)
   xMaxNo = if(xTemp > xMaxNo, xTemp, xMaxNo)
Next

MsgBox("The Highest Number is " & xMaxNo)
```

Comment: this is simple and elegant.